# readFile pauses my code or even promise.all?

Tags: node.js, electron

I need to upload some "big" files to a list of devices.
I have put both readFile() and the Axios requests into promises, but still, my code stops.

On one hand, I notice that the Electron window freezes. And on the other hand, I have an interval in there for testing purposes, which then pauses for a few seconds.

The last response i got is the "console.log(fileReadPromise.length);" then it breaks for some seconds.

```
uploadUpdate(devices, filepath) {
let newDevices = [];

const files = fs.readdirSync(filepath);

let fileReadPromise = [];

fileReadPromise = devices.map(async (dev) => {
  const fwFile = this.setFWtoDevice(files, dev, filepath);
  let url = `https://[${dev.ipv6}]/updateUpload`;
  let cookie = dev.cookie;
  let fwPath = filepath + "//" + fwFile;
  fwPath = path.normalize(fwPath);

  return fs.promises.readFile(fwPath).then((file) => {
    let config = {
      method: "put",
      maxBodyLength: Infinity,
      url: url,
      // timeout: 20000,
      httpsAgent: agent,
      withCredentials: true,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
        Cookie: cookie,
      },
      data: file,
    };
    return axios.request(config).catch((err) => {
      console.log("err", err);
    });
  });
});
console.log(fileReadPromise.length);

return axios
  .all(fileReadPromise)
  .then((responses) => {
    console.log("responses");
    responses.forEach((response) => {
      console.log(response.status);
      if (response?.config == undefined) return;
      let device = this.getDeviceByUrl(response.config?.url, devices);
      //   device.prop = { ...response.data };
      device.status = response.status;
      newDevices.push(device);
    });
    console.log("updateDone");
    return newDevices;
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log("ERR::", err));
```

}